# AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model

I'm using Python 3.7.  I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how and where I should put a method that creates and saves multiple objects.  I have this in my models.py file

```
class ArticleStatManager(models.Manager):
    def save_main_article(self, article):
```

Then in another part of the code, I call

```
ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article(article)
```

but this results in the error

```
    ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article(article)
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'save_main_article'
```

What am I doing wrong or where should I be placing this code so that I can invoke it properly?

Comment: Did you set the ArticleStat objects attribute to point to ArticleStatManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanielRosman point out in his comment, you have to set `ArticleStatManager` as [default manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) (you want it through attribute `objects`, so it has to be the default manager)

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
```

You could also set a different manager just for that purpose:

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = Manager()
    articlesmanager = ArticleStatManager()
```

and then you could:

```
ArticleStat.articlesmanager.save_main_article(article)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the model to use your custom model manager.

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
```

[(DOCS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)